# ADT in C - with or without pointers?

Tags: c, coding-style, adt

In theory it seems that books sugest declaring ADT in C as:

```
struct some_structure;
typedef some_structure *some_structure_t;
```

while most code uses:

```
struct some_structure;
typedef some_structure some_structure_t;
```

I know that `const` is not working with the first style. Is this the only reason for real libraries not to use first approach? Any further notices or suggestions?

Comment: So it seems -- thanks to all nice answers -- that the second style (explicit pointer) is more practical. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you mean *abstract data type*? If I abstract ;-) from the syntax errors in your code snipsets, I think, yes `typedef` of pointer types is frowned upon because problems with `const` and `volatile`.

BTW, another problem with your code are the names you have chosen. `_t` as an ending is reserved for future use in POSIX.

Comment: And only because of this? Is `volatile` really that useful for ADT?

I was not aware of `_t` being reserverd. However many libs do use this convention. Are you aware of any safer conventions (but please no `_T`).

Comment: @dpc.ucore.info an alternative would be to use uppercase for the types, i.e. Some_Structure and lowercase for the functions some_structure_func().

Comment: @dpc.ucore.info: It is good practice for a library that is to be used by many to choose a prefix and stick to that for all symbols that it uses in header files and / or exports in objects. This is e.g done for POSIX threads with `pthread_` for symbols and `PTHREAD_` for macros. (well they again also have the `_t` since it is POSIX.)

Answer (score 2):

An abstract data type is useful as a way of effectively performing actions on something like an "object".

If you can, in C, avoid the "typedef" keyword with structures altogether. It masks what is really happening. As a beginner I recommend you explicitly type `struct AStruct` wherever you would be tempted to use a typedef.

From there you perform an "action" on your "abstract data type" by declaring a function that takes a pointer to the "abstract data type" (or object, as I like to think) as the first parameter, and then the normal parameters afterwards.

e.g.

```
int some_func( struct AStruct *pObject, int param1, int param2 ) {
  if ( ( param1 < 0 ) || ( param2 < 0 ) )
    return( 0 );
  pObject->val = param1 + param2;
  return( 1 );
}
```

Then to use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( void ) {
  struct AStruct myObject;

  if ( some_func( &myObject, 10, 12 ) ) {
    printf( "Processed: %d\n", myObject.val );
  } else {
    printf( "Failed\n" );
  }
  return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: +1 I second the recommendation to avoid `typedef`-ing your structs merely for convenience.  It is only trivially more work to write `struct name` over `name_t`. Retaining the clear indication that the data type is a `struct` can help prevent problems with `const`, as the OP notes.  Being forced to write `struct name*` instead of `name_ptr_t` also avoids some of the indirection confusion that JeremyP mentions in his answer (the pointer is clearly and obviously declared as such).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what other people's code will do with those types.  As a user of your library, if I assume that some_structure_t is a struct instead of a pointer to a struct, I might do something like this:

```
some_structure_t *p;

p = malloc( sizeof *p);
memcpy( p, &another_p, sizeof *p);
```

Maybe it's my background as an embedded programmer, but I want to know more about `some_structure_t` in my code that uses it.  Even if it's a truly abstracted type, and it's only used as a parameter or return value in end-user code, you still have to deal with it in the library that supports the type.  If I saw the following code, I'd do a double take:

```
some_structure_t some_function( some_structure_t foo)
{
    some_structure_t retval;

    retval = malloc( sizeof *retval);  // assigning pointer to struct?
    retval->member = foo->member;      // using -> instead of .?

    return retval;                     // returning potentially large structure on stack?
}
```

And maybe this is the biggest one -- copying from one `some_structure_t` to another.  If it's an `int` or a `float` or a `struct`, writing `foo = bar` will make a copy.  If `some_structure_t` is defined as a pointer to a struct, now `foo` and `bar` point to the same object.  Maybe that's what you want, but it seems risky to me.

I wonder if MISRA has anything to say about typedefs that are pointers.

Comment: Exactly - it's considered bad style in C to hide the fact that a type is a pointer, since the user of the type needs to know that anyway.  Hence the standard library provides `FILE *`.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
typedef struct some_s *some_t;
```

and where it matters I either use `const struct some_s*` or `typedef const struct some_s *const_some_t`, but I guess that's a question of personal taste.

Comment: Declaration of another type for const is a nice idea, thanks.

Comment: Do you handle casting in some fancy way? The functions that promise not to change the object should accept `some_t` in place of `const_some_t`.

Comment: @dpc.ucore.info: you don't have to.  just pass a some_t to a function whose sig is const_some_t, won't issue a warning (at least it doesn't on icc, gcc and pcc).

Answer (score 0):

I used to go with the first style, but I found that I tended to get confused about the levels of indirection I needed to access structure members so I started adding suffixes to the pointer type e.g.

```
typedef struct AStruct *AStructRef;
```

But then I realised I was effectively reinventing the * operator in order to stop myself from being confused by my attempt to hide the * operator.  So now I go with the second style.